# How could I add an integrity seal (hash) of the message payload to the debezium / kafka message

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

It is a business requirement that all the messages I consume from the kafka topic contain an integrity seal so as to identify if any changes were introduced to the message payload.

I was thinking I could possible do this in a kafka connect transform. 
This would require that I convert the payload to the resulting json message format in the transform prior to sealing it so that the results could be verified upon consumption of the message.

My issues currently are...

1) I am not sure how to convert the payload to the same json that would be output to the kafka topic whilst in the transform.

2) I am not sure the best way to add the seal to the message.  It would need to be placed in a consistent location ( for example first ) so that It could be stripped easily/completely prior to validating the seal in the consumer.

Any thoughts, suggestions, different approaches would be appreciated.

Comment: Ideally, transforms shouldn't (de)serialize data, as the Converter externally to the transform would handle that... Not sure what you mean by "consistent location". If you are using JSON or Avro, then you would add a named field, so the ordering doesn't matter.

Comment: @cricket_007 "consistent location" - historically we would convert the entire payload minus the seal into a byte array and calculate the hash.  In this case whitespaces matter, so it has been preferred that the seal be added at the beginning so that the validation process can do so without potentially modifying the whitespace within the payload as well.  Your point is taken though, there is more than one way to achieve this.   Aside from that, are you suggesting I attempt to extend the JsonConverter and seal it there?

Comment: Depending on the attack vectors you want to to address, I'd suggest to look into SSL encrypting the transport layer. This will prevent MITM attacks. If you also want to protect the messages at rest in the broker, you might look into disk encryption.

Comment: Another alternative could be Cleartext [JSON Web Signature (JWS)](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-erdtman-jose-cleartext-jws-00.html), which would let you embed signatures into serialized JSON. For that you could implement a custom serializer based on the existing JSON one.

Comment: @Gunnar Thanks.  SSL transports will be used.  The transport is not what we are protecting here.  We are preventing content from being altered or unsupported messages from being inserted.  The means of accomplishing either of those two issues are outside of my scope - this is not an option but a requirement for me.  We have ways of embedding signatures thanks.  I am really looking for a place I can hook into within the kafka connect source to accomplish this.

Comment: You would have to write your own Transform. You would call [`fromConnectData`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonConverter.java#L330) to get the `byte[]`, then convert that to a string, and hash it based on your logic. You could return a new Struct object with `{hashed_bytes, original_payload}`

Comment: Ok, but if you are using SSL, where do you envision the message manipulation to happen then? In regards to hooking in, I'd use an extended converter as discussed above.

Comment: @Gunnar don't use logic with me.  DOD doesn't appreciate that.